# Million Abbreviation

Tags: labels

What would the correct abbreviation be for million when abbreviating 2,000,000.

I've heard M and MM.

2M or 2MM ?

Comment: Some write *m* but they're wrong by a factor of a billion.

Comment: I think this is more of an english stack exchange question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/149190/what-is-the-correct-abbreviation-for-millions-billions-and-trillions-in-a-finan

Comment: Back when I had a subscription to *The Economist*, I noticed they did it like this: $2-mil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked in and around global finance for over many years and have served on formal audit committees for both private and public companies in the US, Europe, Asia and Australia.  During that time I've seen financial statements from maybe 1000+ different companies and individuals.

There is no standard suffix for millions.  Different banks, consultancies, accountants, investors, brokers, and lawyers will use different suffixes.  Banks and accounting firms have style guides for suffixes (and these are not always followed).  Accountants are the most consistent in usage across the firm (accountants usually avoid using suffixes and spell out `millions` explicitly, or define the numerical units for a given financial statement, e.g. `$ in thousands`).  For consultancies, brokerages, law firms, and corporations the use of suffixes can vary a lot from office to office, team to team, and even different individuals on the same team may use different suffixes.

I've also seen a lot of CFO's try to force staff to standardize suffixes, only to give up because people bring their preferences with them.

- **Million** - The most common suffixes for million are `M`, `MM` and `m`.
  Less common (and more regional) are `mm` and `mil.`
- **Billion** - The most common suffixes are `Bn` and `B`.  Less common are `BN` and `Bil`.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, although it is preferable to use MM instead of M. Please look at this Quora discussion for more information:

https://www.quora.com/What-should-be-the-abbreviation-for-million-M-or-MM